# React - 2 components with same render but different logic

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React and I have come across a problem.
I have a component for adding a user.

AddUser:

```
export default class AddUser extends React.Component {
    onClick() {
        // Save the user.
    }

    render() {
        // Some components.
    }
}
```

Now I want to implement a component to EditUser, the render method is exactly the same, except the text of a button which could be passes through the props.
But the logic is different, the onClick should access a different URL to the api, and it should load the details of the user from the api and put it in the state.

My question is, how to implement this properly?
I thought about making a base component which will be the AddUser component, and the EditUser component will inherit from it and override the componentDidMount method to load the data from the api.

What is the best practice to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Create an `UserForm` component and have an `onSave` prop. For adding new user the parent component should implement `onSave` according to the add logic and for updating another parent component may implement update logic accordingly. You can rename the save button of `UserForm` component according to another prop such as `isUpdate`.

Add Component:

```
import UserForm from "./user_form"
export default class AddUser extends React.Component {
    addUser() {
        // add the user
    }

    render() {
        return <UserForm onSave={this.addUser.bind(this)}>
    }
}
```

Update Component:

```
import UserForm from "./user_form"
export default class UpdateUser extends React.Component {
    updateUser() {
        // add the user
    }

    render() {
        return <UserForm onSave={this.updateUser.bind(this)} isUpdate>
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I have come across a problem.
I have UserForm which contains the user on its state, and it updates it according to the input. In the AddUser component I just render the UserForm and pass the onSave and every thing is fine. But I have some trouble in the EditUser, I need to fetch the data from teh server and then pass it to the UserForm component, and set the state of the UserForm according to the data but the UserForm constructor will occur before I fetch it on the EditUser

Comment: Ok one thing you can do is the fetch the user in updateComponent, then give that to UserForm as a prop, then you can render userForm if there is a user or this is not an update operation. For setting user in UserForm later on, you can use componentWillReceiveProps method. It passes you the next props that will be rendered, and you can check if the current props.user is not same to the nextProps.user you can set the state of user with the nextProps.user.

Comment: I just edited the comment, pressed enter by accident.

Comment: I thought of doing it in the componentDidUpdate of the UserForm, but the componentWillReceiveProps sounds better, but is this the best practice?

Comment: If you have a stateful component and if you are initializing your state according to the given intial props, componentWillReceiveProps is the way to update your state when the given props are changed. Other than this approach you can make a stateless UserForm, but then you need to update user fields in both updateUser and createUser Components, and UserForm will only render the given user.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same component AddUser , just pass the props from the parent component basically the model object which would hold the user value in case of edit.

For the Adduser case the parent component would pass an empty object or null as prop

```
export default class AddUser extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      this.state = {
          firstName: this.props.user ?this.props.user.firstName: ''
      }
    }
    onClick() {
        // Save the user.
      if (this.props.user) {
         //edit user case
     } else {
        //add user case
     }
    }

    render() {
        // Some components.
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a good idea, but when ill use the editUser component, ill have to fetch the user's data from the server on the componentDidMount, which means that the ctor of the AddUser will be called before I have the data on the EditUser.